# Grouper() and agg() functions produce multiple copies when squashed

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science, data-processing

I have a sample dataframe as given below.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

NaN = np.nan
data = {'ID':['A', 'A', 'A', 'B','B','B'],
'Date':['2021-09-20 04:34:57', '2021-09-20 04:37:25', '2021-09-20 04:38:26', '2021-09-01 
 00:12:29','2021-09-01 11:20:58','2021-09-02 09:20:58'],
'Name':['xx','xx',NaN,'yy',NaN,NaN],
'Height':[174,174,NaN,160,NaN,NaN],
'Weight':[74,NaN,NaN,58,NaN,NaN],
'Gender':[NaN,'Male',NaN,NaN,'Female',NaN],
'Interests':[NaN,NaN,'Hiking,Sports',NaN,NaN,'Singing']}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)
df1
```

I want to combine the data present on the same date into a single row. The 'Date' column is in timestamp format. I have written a code for it. Here is my TRY code:

**TRY:**

```
df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date'])

df_out = (df1.groupby(['ID', pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='D')])
         .agg(lambda x: ''.join(x.dropna().astype(str)))
         .reset_index()
     ).replace('', np.nan)
```

This gives an output where if there are multiple entries of same value, the final result has multiple entries in the same row as shown below.

**Obtained Output**
[image]
However, I do not want the values to be repeated if there are multiple entries. The final output should look like the image shown below.

**Required Output**
[image]

The first column should not have 'xx' and 174.0 instead of 'xxxx' and '174.0 174.0'.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: aggregating with `str.join` doesn't seem to be appropriate here for many of the columns. If you expect information to be static, just varying in its missing-ness, then you should use `first` for columns like name, age, weight, gender. But if there are data quality issues, you might want to resolve it with the *modal* value for instance. Then `'Interests'` would be the only column you `','.join`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case replace `agg` `join` to `first`

```
df_out = (df1.groupby(['ID', pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='D')])
         .first()
         .reset_index()
     ).replace('', np.nan)
df_out
Out[113]: 
  ID       Date  Name  Height  Weight  Gender      Interests
0  A 2021-09-20    xx   174.0    74.0    Male  Hiking,Sports
1  B 2021-09-01    yy   160.0    58.0  Female           None
2  B 2021-09-02  None     NaN     NaN    None        Singing
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're only trying to keep the first available value for each column for each date, you can do:

```
>>> df1.groupby(["ID", pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='D')]).agg("first").reset_index()

  ID       Date  Name  Height  Weight  Gender      Interests
0  A 2021-09-20    xx   174.0    74.0    Male  Hiking,Sports
1  B 2021-09-01    yy   160.0    58.0  Female           None
2  B 2021-09-02  None     NaN     NaN    None        Singing
```